# Problems reading serial data on Windows IOT rasberry pi3

Tags: windows, serial-port, uwp, iot, raspberry-pi3

I have an Adafruit Ultimate GPS on a USB serial interface and using the same UWP application can read data just fine on a x86 build on a desktop. When I try a ARM build on the PI3 (remote), everything appears to work, but the serial data read never returns. No timeout, nothing. On the desktop, it starts getting GPS data from the chip right away. I also tried the CustomSerial sample app and am getting the same result. I do have the manifest updated to show serial port access, so don't think that is the problem.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the CustomSerialDeviceAccess sample, you need set Read Timeout to any value greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, operator error. Prolific driver not supported, was trying to read data from on-board serial port. Move the GPS sensor to the on-board serial, all is working now. Apologies for the distraction.